Why can absolute extrema only occur at end-points and where the derivative is 0 or DNE?
When I first learned this it logically made sense to me but after thinking on it after a few days it seems odd to me how extrema only occur at the endpoints and a derivative of 0 or DNE.  Is it really impossible to construct a function where on an interval that is both continuous and differentiable such that there is a value of x who does not meet the aforementioned criteria?  I believe that maybe my lack of understanding on this is because I don't know if the converse of Fermat's theorem is also true?  I'm in calc I and haven't gotten very far in applications of differentiation so I humbly ask for an understandable explanation for someone my level.

So, let's focus on the case where $f'(x_\star)=0$. This means one of three things has happened for $\newcommand{\x}{x_{\star}}
\newcommand{\e}{\varepsilon}
x \approx \x$. More precisely, we consider an open neighborhood $(\x-\e,\x+\e)$, and for $\e$ small enough, one of three things will occur:

$f'(x) = 0$ for all $x$ sufficiently close to $\x$
$f'(x) < 0$ for $x \in (\x-\e,x)$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for $x \in (x,\x+\e)$
$f'(x) > 0$ for $x \in (\x-\e,x)$ and $f'(x) < 0$ for $x \in (x,\x+\e)$

The last two mean that $f$ changes from decreasing to increasing at $\x$, or increasing to decreasing at $\x$, respectively.
Well, it seems natural to see that if such occurs, then the graph makes a "bump" that represents a local extrema. You can see this because, if $f'(x) \ne 0$ at some point $x$, then that means for a sufficiently small neighborhood you should be able to find points $x',x''$ such that $f(x') > f(x) > f(x'')$.
Then the only remaining candidates for global extrema would be the places where these criteria cannot apply: where the function is not differentiable, or at the endpoints.

If you want a more thorough proof, one appears to be on Paul's Online Math Notes.
If you like visuals, I coded up a Desmos demo for my Calculus I students a while ago, which can make clear how the derivative changing sign leads to local extrema.

Thank you!  This cleared it a little.  I think that maybe my main issue is that I haven't even gotten to the first derivative test yet which I suppose is pretty important for differentiating (no pun intended) between extrema and inflexion points.
